# Cast void* to char*

Tags: c, casting

I have a `char *` who points to the structure. Here is my structure:

```
struct prot
{
    int size;
    unsigned short codeAction;
    void *data;
};
```

I recovered `size` and `codeAction`, but now I want to recover `data`. 
And when I cast my last 8 bytes I have nothing in it.

The following code is just a test, it's a bad code:

```
char lol[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    lol[i] = test[i];

int size = *(int*)lol;

char loli[2];
int index = 0;   
for (int i = 4; i < 6; i++)
{
    loli[index] = test[i];
    index++;
}

int code = *(short*)loli;

char lolo[8];
index = 0;
for (int i = 6; i < size; ++i)
{
    lolo[index] = test[i];
    index++;
}

void *newData = (char *)lolo; // how can I cast it?
```

How I can display the content of `newData`?

Comment: How did you write out the data in the first place?  You should really consider using a serialization library that handles this stuff for you.

Comment: It seems to me you would get a better response with the c tag than with the c++ tag.

Comment: What is the type of `test`?

Comment: what's the type of test

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that when casting `lolo` you actually cast a pointer to the char array you defined. So the result of the cast would be a `char` pointer to the first cell of the array.

Why don't you just use this as a struct and access the fields regularly?

Anyway, you want to use `lolo` as a 64 bit type pointer and the access what's in it.

```
void* newData = *((uint64_t*)lolo)
```

Besides, don't loop until `size` in the last `for` loop, loop only 8 times, until `lolo` is full. The number of bytes in `newData` itself (**not** what it points to) is constant, and is 4 bytes on 32bit machines, 8 bytes on 64bit ones.

Last thing -  `index++`, not `o++`. `o` isn't defined, as much as I can see.